# android - custom round imageView get error inflating

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

I've a listview and I use a custom layout for making rows . in each row ,I've custom imageView for rounding images . This is the class:

```
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();

    Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
    canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

}

public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
    Bitmap sbmp;
    if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius)
        sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, radius, radius, false);
    else
        sbmp = bmp;
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight(),
            Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xffa19774;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
    canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2 + 0.7f,
            sbmp.getHeight() / 2 + 0.7f, sbmp.getWidth() / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

}

the above code works fine if it doesn't used in an adapter .

this is my adapter code :

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Activity activity;
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list;

    public ListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>list ) {
        super();
        this.activity=(Activity)activity;
        this.list=list;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return contactList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return contactList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imguser; 
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ads, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imguser=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imguser);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        HashMap<String, String> item = contactList.get(position);
        imageLoader.displayImage("http://192.168.1.35/test/usersPic/"+item.get("profileImg"), holder.imguser,
                options, imageListener);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

this is the error I get :

```
    03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.tejarat.example.RoundedImageView
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at com.tejarat.example.Fragment_C$ListAdapter.getView(Fragment_C.java:168)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1247)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1159)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1451)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:704)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-23 05:30:02.853: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:73
```

Could you help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: post your xml code as well

Comment: do you use com.tejarat.example.RoundedImageView in your xml code for ImageView tag?If so replace 'com.tejarat.example' with your package name(if this's not your package name).

Comment: @KarthikaPB  yes it's my package name

Answer (score 0):

Refresh your project and just check that if your custom roundimageview in your xml redirect you to your class file when you clicked on it.

Answer (score 0):

In your `getView()` Method change the line:

```
holder.imguser=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imguser);
```

with this one:

```
holder.imguser=(RoundedImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imguser);
```

There could be other issues but this one is currently visible.

Comment: not worked , I've used it before as an imageView and it did work .

Comment: In your xml you must have to replace the `ImageView` tag with `com.tejarat.example.RoundedImageView`

and you also have to use `RoundedImageView` in the java. But its tough to assume whats going wrong out there. Actually you need to replace all the ImageView from your adapter. Other wise it will not be able to execute

Comment: I've done this already , I've defined com.tejarat.example.RoundedImageView in my xml code .

Comment: And did you replaced all the imageView with RoundedImageView in CustomAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

in your adapter please check passing parameter:

```
imageLoader.displayImage("http://192.168.1.35/test/usersPic/"+item.get("profileImg"), holder.imguser,
                options, imageListener);
```

options ??

Have you initialize options value.
please check.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using simply including

```
mOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheOnDisc(true)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.noimage_round)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.noimage_round)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.adapter_main_width)))
                .build();
```

and

```
  mImageLoader.displayImage(searchImage, holder.sThumb, mOptions);
```

will create rounded images